# How to add dynamic height and width in the backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, styling

Instead of hardcoding this `height` and `width` I want to calculate the `height` and `width` according to the data.

```
let options;
if (
  animalsDetails.hasOwnProperty('animals') &&
  animalsDetails.animals.length > 8 &&
  animalsDetails.animals.length < 16
) {
  options = { height: '25in', width: '11in' };
} else if (
  animalsDetails.hasOwnProperty('animals') &&
 animalsDetails.animals.length > 16
) {
  options = { height: '30in', width: '11in' };
} else {
  options = { height: '18in', width: '11in' };
}
```

Comment: Fetch height and width data from API and store in a variable then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic height and width is something which should be managed at frontend side as in front we have an object **window** and The Window interface is home to a variety of functions, namespaces, objects, and constructors, etc... so you can get the screen size and other parameters related to window size very easily using window.

- **Design perspective** :
  If you want dynamic height and width for designing purpose, then that should be managed in css using media query, where you can define the screen size and apply styles
- **Backend perspective** : When JavaScript is used in backend i.e., node js, the "window" object is not accessible and we have "global" which do not return screen resolution or screen size related data.

So, there is only one way to get the dynamic height and width is get the details from frontend side via API call.